# computation of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\theta^{2n+1}}\exp\left(- \frac1{\theta^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, self-learning

I encountered this integral in proving that a function is an approximation to the identity. But I don't know how to solve this integral. I would greatly appreciate any help. How can I calculate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\frac{1}{\theta^{2n+1}}\exp\left(-\frac1{\theta^2}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)d\theta\,?$$

Comment: have you made any attempts?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Using a $u$-sub $x = \theta^{-1}$, we get
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{\theta^{2n+1}} e^{-c/\theta^2}\ d\theta = \int^\infty_0 x^{2n-1}e^{-cx^2}\ dx.
\end{align}
where $c = \sum x_i^2$. Then use integration by parts.

Comment: To circumvent the integration by parts, one can note that the final expression is $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial c^{n-1}} \int_0^{\infty} xe^{-cx^2}$

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with is as follows: $-z=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2,$
and 
$ v=1/\theta^2.$
This is a setup for a "$u-$substitution." You get the following:
$$\frac{dv}{-2v\sqrt{v}}=d\theta,$$
and your integral becomes
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\theta^{2n+1}}e^\frac{-z}{\theta^2}d\theta=\int_0^\infty v^n\sqrt{v}e^{-zv}\frac{dv}{-2v\sqrt{v}}$$
which yields

$$ -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty v^{n-1}e^{-zv}dv.$$

To me this looks an awful lot like the Gamma function

$$ \Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx,$$ and this conversion might help you with your proof.